# How to make a query to get discriminated values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-administration

I have an application with 4 tables:

> Employees -> Companies -> Additionals -> Debts

I need to generate this following salary receipt:

[Receipt Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2GXZ.png)

On this document I have to show all discriminated information as SALARY and its value and fees. And at the end the net value between additionals and debts.

I made this example:

```
$total_additional= 0;
$total_debt= 0;

// Here in employees contains a join between employees and companies
foreach ($employees as $employee) {

  foreach ($additionals as $additional) {
    if ( $employee->id == $additional->employee_id ) {
     //Print the additional reference
     $total_additional += $additional->value;
    }
  }

  foreach ($debts as $debt) {
    if ( $employee->id == $debt->employee_id ) {
     //Print the debt reference
     $total_debt += $debt->value;
    }
  }

  // Here should come the net value

}
```

How can I make a query to fetch those results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using some `LEFT JOIN`s, `GROUP BY` clause and `SUM` aggregations to get all data in one query without having to loop in PHP?

```
SELECT employees.id, employees.name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(additionals.value SEPARATOR '|') as additionals_values, SUM(additionals.value) as total_additional
FROM employees
LEFT JOIN additionals ON additionals.employee_id = employees.id
GROUP BY employees.id, employees.name;

SELECT employees.id, employees.name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(debts.value SEPARATOR '|') as debts_values, SUM(debts.value) as total_debt
FROM employees
LEFT JOIN debts ON debts.employee_id = employees.id
GROUP BY employees.id, employees.name;
```

In php use `explode('|'...` to have an array of individual values. Net value can be calculated with 3'rd query or in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it helps but I need also to list each Additional and Debt with name and value not only to total as you can see in the image on the question...

Comment: TBH If I would have to do it I would still go with the group by and add `GROUP_CONCAT()` to the `SELECT` clause just to save on the SQL queries and php loops (my experience made me pretty concerned about those two).

Comment: Could u give me an example ?

Comment: Between this solution and the one that I was using do you consider a gain of performance ? For the names I could use another GROUP_CONCAT() right ?

Comment: I was testing here and it brings duplicated values, like If the query returns 4 entries it duplicates the values by 4....

Comment: Yeah, I didn't fully think this edit through, two left joins are causing duplications. Split this SQL in two, separate for `additionals` and separate for `debts`. I'll give an example in the response edit.

Comment: Re. performance - this approach is for sure better PHP-performance-wise - you will only loop though data you know you are going to use (no `if`s checking employee's id). For small amount of data gain may be very low or even there can be none, but the more data in DB the more this approach will be faster when compared to the original fetch-all-and-loop-through-it solution (assuming proper indices/primary keys are set in database).

Comment: re. __For the names I could use another GROUP_CONCAT() right ?__

If you are talking about employee's name, then you should add it to the GOUP BY clause and fetch it, no need to concat it.